# Including data files in PyScaffold 3.0.x with setup.cfg

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, setup.py

as often happens with python packaging tools, I'm having troubles packaging data files with my code.

I'm using PyScaffold 3.0.1 and the setup.cfg right now doesn't contain any `data_files` or `package_data` option because they don't seem to work. I tried to use them in many different way but they all seem to refer to setup.cfg used without pyscaffold or to previous version of pyscaffold.

The option `include_package_data = True` is still there.

The folder structure is like the following

.

```
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── src
│   ├── my_package
│   │   ├── benchmarks.py
│   │   ├── client.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── libs
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── libt1.so
│   │   │   └── libt2.so
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   │   ├── dataset.csv
│   │   │   └── __init__.py
├── tests
│   ...
```

The code to load the resource through `pkg_resource` is correct because if I run from `pytest` or if I copy the file in the expected location, the program runs.

The files are not present in the .egg file produced with sdist.

How do I include these files?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the setuptools_scm was in the middle and these files weren't committed during my experiments. By committing the files everything work